Are the PS/2 interfaces of the Gigabyte mainboard GA-A320M-H-CF native, or attached to a PS/2-to-USB converter?
When trying out a very old (made in 1994, but unused) Siemens PS/2 keyboard on my machine built around a Gigabyte GA-A320M-H-CF mainboard, the keyboard showed strange bahavior: Many Non-PC-keys like F15, F16, as well as F18 thru F22, did not emit any scancodes. After a question from an expert on old keyboards whether I'm using a PS/2-to-USB converter (which is afaik false, as I plugged the keyboard plug directly into the jack on the mainboard), I suspect that the PS/2 interfaces on the mainboard are in fact attached to the chipset (AMD A320) via an on-board PS/2-to-USB converter.
Can this be true? The mainboard manual says nothing about this matter. BTW, i used xev on OpenSuSE 15.5 to test the keyboard.

It would be very unlikely seems unnecessary complicated board design

You have the mobo. Did you try a verbose lsusb to see what USB devices are in your system?  What are "Non-PC-keys"?  BTW describing an observation as "strange bahavior" is not helpful. "Strange" simply means that you (and not necessarily others) are unfamiliar with it.

I'm gonna try out 'lsusb'. And no, "strange" in this context simply means "not working as expected".

OK, I've found it out myself by looking at the output of lsusb, once with the Siemens PS/2 keyboard pluggid in, and once with my USB-based everyday KB:
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 05e3:0732 Genesys Logic, Inc. All-in-One Cardreader
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1038:1702 SteelSeries ApS SteelSeries Rival 100 Gaming Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 040b:6543 Weltrend Semiconductor Manhattan Magnetic Card Strip Reader
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

vs.
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 0430:00a2 Fujitsu Component Limited Type 7 Keyboard
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0430:100e Fujitsu Component Limited 24.1" LCD Monitor v4 / FID-638 Mouse
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 05e3:0732 Genesys Logic, Inc. All-in-One Cardreader
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1038:1702 SteelSeries ApS SteelSeries Rival 100 Gaming Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 040b:6543 Weltrend Semiconductor Manhattan Magnetic Card Strip Reader
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

So there's apparently no PS/2-to-USB bridge involved.
